# Node.js: Why is my expected value not returned in 'catch' block of 'try-catch' clause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, try-catch, webdriver-io

I have a Node.js project which tests the functionality of a website.  It utilizes Webdriver.io v4 and Mocha/Chai.

I've created a function that checks if an element exists on a page with a timeout of 1 minute.  If the element exists, it should return `true`.  If it does not, it should return `false`.

I use the same function to test if an element is NOT present on the page.  In this case, I am expecting the function to return `false`.  However, instead of returning false, the function throws a Timeout error and returns neither `true` or `false`.  This is strange because I've included a `return false` statement in the catch block of my try-catch clause.

In this project, when a function fails, I will get a message such as `expected false to equal true` or `expected undefined to equal true`. In this case, I get the message `Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/timeouts.html); if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Yes, I am expecting the `element.waitForExist()` to throw a Timeout error, but this error should be handled in the catch block by returning `false`.  The program does display the error log as expected by the `console.log(ex)` line, but does not return `false`.

Why is my function not returning `false` in this case?  What would be the best/easiest way to return the correct value? Thank you!

This is my function:

```
checkElementExists: {
        value: function (element) {
            try {
                element.waitForExist();
                if (element.isExisting()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected: If element exists on page, the function returns `true`.  If the element does not exist on the page, the function returns `false`.

Actual: If element exists on page, the function returns `true`.  If the element does not exist on the page, a Timeout error is thrown but neither `true` or `false` is returned.

Comment: a catch block catches exceptions, not valid returns. just because it is false does not mean it would run the catch block.

Comment: @HolyMoly I don't understand what you mean.  I'm expecting the function to return `false` when the element is not present.  The function checks to see if the element is present or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the problem of value not being returned, please try the below approach. I am not sure why `catch` fails to return, but could you please try the below:

```
checkElementExists: {
    value: function (element) {
        let val = false;
        try {
            element.waitForExist();
            if (element.isExisting()) {
                val = true;
            } 
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Naveen.  Unfortunately this approach does not work either.  It is strange that the return value is not returned.  I think I will ask the WDIO team to see if they have an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: @Brian ,.. quick question.. what is the `mocha` timeout in the conf file?

Comment: I guess the issue is not because the timeout of `waitForExist()`, it is because the `mocha` timeout in the conf file has exceeded

Comment: My `mocha` timeout and `waitForTimeout` are both `60000` (one minute).  I see where you're going with this.  I will try to set the `waitForTimeout` to be `30000` (30 seconds).

Comment: That did the trick!!!! Thank you so much Naveen, I was really scratching my head over this one!  Thanks again :]